Редактирование файла xml с помощью vbs
Есть фрагмент файла xml:
            ' <section sid="2" name="Доступ к базам данных" icon="22" slide="-1">
                ' <param id="9" name="Источник данных" ctrl="button_string" value="pgsql:ncad_24_0"/>
                ' <param id="13153" name="Путь к внешним файлам проектов" ctrl="dialog_system_folder_browser" hidden="1" value="[DATA_ALL_RW]"/>
                ' <param id="12" ctrl="edit_int" hidden="1" name="Standards filter" value="1021"/>
                ' <param id="13" name="Фильтр стандартов" ctrl="button_string" hidden="1" value="ЕСКД, ISO, DIN, JUS, PN, GB, CSN, NF, IS"/>
                ' <param id="14" name="Фильтр номенклатуры" ctrl="button_string" hidden="1" value="Отключен"/>
            ' </section>

Подскажите пожалуйста, как внести изменения в файл xml, заменив значение в value="pgsql:ncad_24_0", на value="C:\ProgramData\Nanosoft\nanoCAD x64 24.0\DataRW\std.mdf".
Начало кода на vbs:
Dim xmlDoc, objNode
Dim strFile 
Dim strUserName
strUserName = "C:\ProgramData\Nanosoft\nanoCAD x64 24.0\DataRW\std.mdf"

' Path to your xml file
strFile = "C:\AppOptions.xml"

' Create an xml Documment object and load your file
Set xmlDoc =  CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.Async = "False"
xmlDoc.Load strFile

  
' Save the changes
xmlDoc.Save strFile

' Clean up
If Not objNode Is Nothing Then
    Set objNode = Nothing
End If

Set xmlDoc = Nothing

Я так понимаю, что нужно поиском найти строку и заменить ее.
